# Geolocation calculating distance as 0?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I've been working on this for a while and it's been throwing problems at me all day. I'm at the point now where I'm really stuck and not sure where to go next. I'll point out I'm pretty new to Javascript so it's possibly a noob error.

Anyway the overall aim is for it to check the users current location and then check whether they're in a 200m radius of the target coordinates. When I enter my current coordinates, it runs the alert in the OnInterval function however it doesn't run if they're in the 200m radius.

Does anyone know how to fix this? :X

```
var userPositionLat;
var userPositionLong;

jQuery(window).ready(function() {  
    initiate_geolocation();
});

function initiate_geolocation() {  
    //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query,handle_errors);
    // http://www.thedotproduct.org/2010/04/example-of-navigator-geolocation-watchposition/
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(handle_geolocation_query,handle_errors, {enableHighAccuracy:true, maximumAge:30000});
}

function handle_errors(error) {  
    switch(error.code)  
    {  
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("user did not share geolocation data");  
        break;

        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("could not detect current position");  
        break;

        case error.TIMEOUT: alert("retrieving position timed out");  
        break;

        default: alert("unknown error");  
        break;
    }  
}  



function handle_geolocation_query(position) {
    userPositionLat = position.coords.latitude;
    userPositionLong = position.coords.longitude;

    alert('Your latitude is :'+userPositionLat+' and longitude is '+userPositionLong);

    IsUserNearTarget();
}


function CalculateDistance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2) {
    // Translate to a distance
    var distance =
            Math.sin(lat1 * Math.PI) * Math.sin(lat2 * Math.PI) +
            Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI) * Math.cos(Math.abs(long1 - long2) * Math.PI);

    // Return the distance in meters
    return Math.acos(distance) * 6370981.162;
}

function IsUserNearTarget()
{
    // The target longitude and latitude
    var targetlong = 0.0; //change this with your coordinates to test
    var targetlat = 0.0; //change this with your coordinates to test

    // Start an interval every 1s
    var OurInterval = setInterval(OnInterval, 1000);

    // Call this on an interval
    function OnInterval() {
        var distance = CalculateDistance(targetlat, targetlong, userPositionLat, userPositionLong);

        // Is it in the right distance? (200m)
        if (distance <= 200) {
            // Stop the interval
            clearInterval(OurInterval);

            alert('TOTALLY WORKS BRO');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert degrees to radians, multiply by `π/180`, not `π`.